# Помогите нарисовать canvas!

Tags: javascript, html, css

Просьба помочь нарисовать canvas. Необходимо после сделать анимацию отрисовки этого canvas при скролле. JS код для скролла написала, а вот canvas вообще не знаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нарисовать в inkscape  взять path от туда и вставить в `beginPath()` вроде бы так

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: если получится напишите

Comment: Да, обязательно напишу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc000'

  var p = new Path2D("M 87.309014,9.6815981 C 109.3243,60.00378 146.75974,79.485664 184.54955,98.258795 125.13447,108.87839 113.83075,141.06513 112.2624,177.61602 93.824599,138.22508 67.495779,104.40427 15.021869,89.038824 57.034865,79.449738 79.550768,51.510449 87.309014,9.6815981 Z");
  ctx.stroke(p);
  ctx.fill(p);
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пользуясь Вашим советом я получила следующие данные:

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="300"
   height="291"
   viewBox="0 0 300 291"
   fill="none"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg3727"
   sodipodi:docname="vector_canvas.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3733">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3731" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     id="namedview3729"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.81099656"
     inkscape:cx="150"
     inkscape:cy="145.5"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg3727" />
  <path
     d="M138.5 290.5C138.5 290.5 120.5 259 81.5 223C42.5 187 0.5 172 0.5 172C0.5 172 65.3065 130.883 96.5 94C124.093 61.374 152.5 0 152.5 0C152.5 0 185.551 45.6 217.5 71C249.912 96.7682 300 116.5 300 116.5C300 116.5 244 148 204 192C164 236 138.5 290.5 138.5 290.5Z"
     fill="#A7C6CF"
     id="path3725" />
</svg
```

Исходя из этого кода хотела сделать анимацию на появление элемента. Чтобы он прорисовывался от 0 до своей высоты. Это так и не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Я пошла иным путем.

```
line {
        position: absolute;
        height: 436px;
        width: 480px;
        bottom: -218px;
        left: -166px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(17deg);
        transform: rotate(17deg);
        stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
        stroke-dasharray: 2000;
        stroke-width: 20;
        transition: stroke-dashoffset 10s;
        z-index: -1;
        overflow: hidden;

        &:before {
            content: '';
            width: 275px;
            height: 270px;
            background-color: $color_white;
            border-radius: 100% 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
            transform: rotate(-23deg);
            left: -119px;
            bottom: 127px;
        }

        &:after {                
            content: '';
            width: 255px;
            height: 297px;
            background-color: $color_white;
            border-radius: 100% 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
            transform: rotate(-7deg);
            left: 200px;
            bottom: 11px;
        }

        &_icon {
            height: 500px;
            width: 350px;
            padding-left: 32px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            stroke: $color_btn;
            stroke-width: 250;
        }
    }
```

И сделала анимацию с помощью stroke-dashoffset: 0;

Comment: path надо было взять ...а не весь хлам из inkscape и сохранить как `простой svg`или даже зайти в редактор XML и прям о туда без сохранения самого документа взять path

Comment: Этот "хлам" мне выдала программа которую ты посоветовал.

Comment: я же говорил о path а не обо всём документе